# Unable to read public DataTable stored on an MDI Container form

Tags: c#, datagridview, datatable

I have a public DataTable on my MDI Container form that I load data into when the application loads. I’ve verified that the DataTable is not null at this point.

I want to populate a DGV on a child form with data from the public DataTable. When I do this, the DGV is blank and when I check if data exists in the public DataTable using the code below it says the public DataTable is Null?

However, when I check if on a child form to the  DataTable on the MDI Container, the data is null?

```
        if (formMain.dataTableCustomers != null)
        {
            if (formMain.dataTableCustomers.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Data exists!");
            }
        }
        else
        { MessageBox.Show("No Data!"); }
```

Can anyone tell me where I might be going wrong?

Comment: Please create a [mcve]

Comment: I can pass data from formA DataTable to formB DataTable without issue. But if formA is an MDI container form, this process does not work.